google_ads_iframe link in the head section of some of my site web page
Why is this:
<link href="data:text/css,%3Ais(%5Bid*%3D'google_ads_iframe'%5D%2C%5Bid*%3D'taboola-'%5D%2C.taboolaHeight%2C.taboola-placeholder%2C%23credential_picker_container%2C%23credentials-picker-container%2C%23credential_picker_iframe%2C%5Bid*%3D'google-one-tap-iframe'%5D%2C%23google-one-tap-popup-container%2C.google-one-tap-modal-div%2C%23amp_floatingAdDiv%2C%23ez-content-blocker-container)%20%7Bdisplay%3Anone!important%3Bmin-height%3A0!important%3Bheight%3A0!important%3B%7D" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 

showing up in the head section of my web pages? I didn't put it there.
What's it for?
I am not expecting it to be there.

You have given us no information about your website or what it's using for us to give you a meaningful answer to your question. Please read How do I ask a good question and provide more details about the problem.

I noticed the exact same header in my Firefox browser today and found out that it only appeared when I have the DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials extension activated. Couldn't figure out how exactly it works though, but maybe that information helps.

I noticed the same CSS link in the <head> of pages on a local non-internet facing Apache site at home. Looking further I found it in just about any page I browse with Firefox. Like @dude mentioned, I see it when I have the DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials extension activated.
I found a reddit post that seems to shed some light
https://www.reddit.com/r/duckduckgo/comments/14r3vde/does_duckduckgo_privacy_essentials_firefox_uses/
